# Local copy of the 'value' of the database and security concerns

Tags: datomic

As I understand it, a datomic database is downloaded/copied onto the peer and all queries are done on the peer. How is this secure? If the user is only authorized to view certain data but actually has all the data on his machine, where is the security logic to stop him accessing data he shouldn't?

thanks

Comment: I'm no expert, but I can search SO, so maybe this addresses your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510528/access-control-in-datomic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peers are not user machines, they are the group of processes that (along with the transactor) constitute the database.  Peers are often application servers.